# I tried importing ImageEnhance from PIL but got an OSERROR, How do I correct this?

Tags: python, image, import, python-imaging-library

The code:

```
from PIL import ImageEnhance
```

gave this error :-

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-84203ab35a9e> in <module>
----> 1 from PIL import ImageEnhance

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3env\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageEnhance.py in <module>
      19 #
      20 
 ---> 21 from . import Image, ImageFilter, ImageStat
      22 
      23 

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3env\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFilter.py in <module>
      21 
      22 try:
 ---> 23     import numpy
      24 except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
      25     numpy = None

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
      140     from . import _distributor_init
      141 
  --> 142     from . import core
      143     from .core import *
      144     from . import compat

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
      21             # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
      22             # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
 ---> 23             WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
      24             DLL_filenames.append(filename)
      25     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

~\Anaconda3\envs\py3env\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, 
  use_last_error)
      354 
      355         if handle is None:
  --> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
      357         else:
      358             self._handle = handle

 OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: it seems it has problem to import module `numpy` - do you have installed module `numpy` ?

Comment: Please specify details to reproduce the error? OS, installation steps, versions, etc.